# link with icon in header alignment

Tags: html, css

My header is devided in 3 sections: `left`, `center` and `right`. The `left` section is empty. In the `center` section I have my page title and in the `right` section I placed an "Account" link with an icon next to it. The link contains the word ACCOUNT and an icon. the icon is somehow pushed to the top and leaves a blank space below it next to the word. I want them both in one line and on the same hight. How can I achieve this? I added a red background to make the problem better understandable.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  overflow: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#in {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
}


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */


/* -------------------------------- HEADER -------------------------------- */


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

header {
  background-color: #131b23;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #0f151a;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#left {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 164px;
}

#center {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
  height: 164px;
}

#right {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 164px;
}

#heading {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.accountlink {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 15px;
}

.navigationicon {
  position: relative;
  width: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="center">
      <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <a class="accountlink" href="login.html">Account <img class="navigationicon" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-512.png"></a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Is this what you see? https://imgur.com/a0g8ph9

Comment: Yes pleas open the snippet on full screen. I havn't included the css for smaller devices

Comment: Add more space to your `#right` (25% width works in my tests) and set your `.navigationicon` to `float: right;`. That should do it. https://i.imgur.com/xI39Ov6.png

Comment: thanks but now there is a gap below the ACCOUNT how can I have the word and the icon in one line centered horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this ?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  overflow: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#in {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
}


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */


/* -------------------------------- HEADER -------------------------------- */


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

header {
  background-color: #131b23;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #0f151a;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 170px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#left {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 164px;
}

#center {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  right: 25%;
  height: 164px;
}

#right {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 164px;
}

#heading {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.accountlink {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 20px;
  background: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios-7-icons/50/user_male2-512.png");
  background-size: 24px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: right;
  background-position-y: 0px;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="center">
      <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="right">      
      <a class="accountlink" href="login.html">Account </a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Four changes to your css code to get there: 2 at .navigationicon and 2 at .accountlink

```
 .accountlink {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 70px;
 }

.navigationicon {
  position: relative;
  width: 12px;
  margin: 0 0 2px -5px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
}
```